Google Billing 7.1.0 documentation is not available on Android Studio
I cant get the documentation for Billing-ktx on Android Studio, I've checked the documentation file and its the same that is available on the official link https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=billing#com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:7.1.0.
Does it work for anyone in this version?
Someone know how to fix it? It's very helpful to be able to read the documentation in AS while coding.
My Android Studio is "Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1"

I've tryed to replace the file for the javadoc already, also I tryed to set the link to the documentation too, nothing worked.
